# How can I get the grub menu on boot?

Tags: 10.04, grub2, iso, bootloader

This is for a friend's Toshiba Portege laptop with Ubuntu 10.4.1 on it. They want the original Windows XP for tablet PC installed; they do have the disk, but the Portege seems unable to boot from a generic non-Toshiba USB CD drive (and the Toshiba one that came with it is broken for years now).

So I found out about [plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html). I followed the instructions (modified; I touched /etc/grub.d/40_custom or something) and now the executable '/boot/plpbt.bin' (I copied it there of course) is included as an option (I hope! I ran `update-grub2` and `update-grub` and verified that the custom menu option exists in /boot/grub/grub.cfg).

I cannot bring up the grub menu at boot; <kbd>Esc</kbd> unfortunately jumps to the Portege BIOS, and I haven't managed to succeed in getting grub to choose the Plop boot manager.

How can I bring up the grub menu on boot?

Comment: I'm not sure you need plop. GRUB2 can load ISO-images itself without any extra help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bring up GRUB by pressing SHIFT during boot. If you want to permanently show grub, edit the respective options in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: You say that grub2 can load ISO images. Great! All I've got is an external USB CD drive. Can you give me directions?

Comment: you answered this question; I also opened [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8919) question about how to boot an ISO CD from an external USB drive.