# Can I make grub2 boot from a CD in an external USB CD drive?

Tags: 10.04, grub2, usb-drive, bootloader

I would like to boot from an external USB CD/DVD drive on a Toshiba Portege which can't. I've tried with [plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html), but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but your only options seems to be plop. I have successfully tried on a computer whose BIOS that doesn't allow booting from USB-CD-Drive.

GRUB2 itself doesn't support booting from a CD-Drive but it supports booting from ISO files.

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS must support booting from USB.